fftshift or convolve from NumPy module incorrect operation
I'm trying to show in Python equivalence of two signals multiplication in time domain to convolution of them in frequency domain.
Thanks to Baddioes in this post, it was shown that such equivalence can be shown by using fftshift function, but the example was done in Matlab. I expected to get absolutely the same result in Python, but it is not the same, the code is below:
f = 2e6
t = np.linspace(0,1,64)

x = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*0.5*f*t)

# multiplication in time domain
signal_xy = x*y

# Fourier of multiplied signals and individual signal
FFT_xy = np.fft.fft(signal_xy)
FFT_x = np.fft.fft(x)
FFT_y = np.fft.fft(y)

# plot the result
plt.plot(abs(FFT_xy))
plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.convolve(np.fft.fftshift(FFT_x),np.fft.fftshift(FFT_y), 'same')))/len(FFT_x), linestyle='--')


I also tried to use fftshift and convolve from scipy module, but the result is absolutely the same.
Does fftshift and convolve functions work correctly in Python?

You need to use ifftshift to shift the result back (after shifting with fftshift). ifftshift moves the origin back to the first sample.

@CrisLuengo, could you please give me an example of using ifftshift function to solve the issue?

The last line should be plt.plot(np.fft.ifftshift(abs(np.convolve(np.fft.fftshift(FFT_x),np.fft.fftshift(FFT_y), 'same')))/len(FFT_x), linestyle='--') — I don’t know if this is the main issue in your code or not, but this is the correct way to use fftshift and ifftshift.

There’s also the possibility that convolve is not preserving the location of the origin, because your signal is not odd in size. I don’t know how this function picks the origin for even-sized inputs. Try to make your input odd in length to disambiguate.

@CrisLuengo, I tried different odd lengths of the signal and the result was very weird, there is still no universal solution fot this problem((

@Curious, I've modified my answer to adapt the numpy.convolve routine to a periodic one consistent with the convolution theorem. That seems to work for general n (and other signals). Despite your linked post in another forum, I actually think that there is no reason to shift anything at all (especially as you are just going to shift it back again). In fact, I think shifting is just "papering over the cracks" - it's simply moving the limited zone where there are significant FFT values into the centre, where they are less affected by boundary effects in the convolution.

@lastchance, thank you so much for a very nice and comprehensive explanation!) btw, in my answer in dsp.stackexcange.com I mentioned, that I've already used such method (doubling FFT_x or FFT_y signal) and it seemed to me as some hack, so now I can see that it is only way to work with my problem) thanks!)

(This is a heavily-edited answer, so I won't be offended if those who upticked it withdraw their vote.)
Original Answer (more general one to follow)
You can control the shifting and do it yourself using numpy.roll(). (Note the reversable shifting distances n//2-1 and n//2+1 in the below). Unfortunately, this is ad-hoc (and doesn't actually work for other values of n).
n=len(x)
plt.plot(abs(FFT_xy))
plt.plot(np.roll(abs(np.convolve(np.roll(FFT_x,n//2-1),np.roll(FFT_y,n//2-1), 'same')),n//2+1)/n, linestyle='--')

What I think is the real problem
The convolution theorem ("FFT of convolution = product of FFTs") only holds if the x, y arrays have periodic extensions. However, numpy.convolve doesn't do that - it zero pads as below. For arrays of equal length this means that the convolution is only actually consistent with the periodic version at a single point.

A simple solution is to wrap the np.convolve() function with one which first doubles the length of the first array, then only takes the N to 2N-1 elements, which should be consistent with periodic arrays.

Full code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def conv( A, B ):
    N = len( A )
    AA = np.concatenate( ( A, A ) )
    return np.convolve( AA, B, 'full' )[N:2*N]

f = 2e6
t = np.linspace(0,1,64)

x = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*0.5*f*t)

# multiplication in time domain
signal_xy = x*y

# Fourier of multiplied signals and individual signal
FFT_xy = np.fft.fft(signal_xy)
FFT_x = np.fft.fft(x)
FFT_y = np.fft.fft(y)

# plot the result
n = len( x )

# Forward plot ("Product of FFTs equals FFT of convolution")
plt.plot(abs(FFT_x*FFT_y))
plt.plot( abs(np.fft.fft( conv(x,y) ) ), linestyle='--')

# Backward plot ("FFT of product equals convolution of FFTs / N") - this was what was wanted by the OP
#plt.plot( abs(FFT_xy))
#plt.plot( abs( conv(FFT_x,FFT_y) ) / n, linestyle='--')

plt.show()

In the forward direction ("FFT of convolution = product of FFTs") we get

In the backward direction (which actually what the OP wanted and can be found by switching the commented/uncommented lines in the code) this gives the following. Note that there is no need to shift the FFTs only to shift them back again.

It is possible that Matlab may already work with implied periodicity when it does the convolution, but I'm not in a position to check.

thanks) but I already use exactly this solution with np.roll function)

@lastchance, sorry, I forgot to mention, that I've already used np.roll function, but still even with the usage of np.roll function it looks like some "hack" (compared to Matlab for example)

Yes, I agree: the rolling was picked off here by trial and error, so definitely a hack. I’ll see if I can work out exactly what numpy.convolve is doing (and remind myself how the convolution theorem works in discrete space). This rolling only works for even length, so I’ll have to find a general version.

I've heavily edited my post, @Curious, to wrap the numpy.convolve function so that it works with the periodicity implicit in the convolution theorem.
